# Expected spy getAssetById to have been called

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jasmine, ngx-bootstrap

Hi ive been working on a fix for the TABS fired select event(bug in ngx-bootstrap) https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3755 and saw this fix in the thread https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3755#issuecomment-387211938 which I am currently using on all of my components that but I had an issue with one of my components and units tests which is currently failing the last test(should call loadAsset)

by the way im using angular and typescript

component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routeParamSubscription = this.route.params.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(params => {
      this.assetId = params['id'];
      this.loadAsset();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // required by untilDestroyed
  }

  private loadAsset() {
    this.loaded = false;
    this.assetManagementService
      .getAssetById(this.assetId)
      .pipe(
        tap({
          next: asset => {
            this.asset = asset;
            this.loadTimelineEntries();
          },
        }),
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.loadHeaderActions();
          this.loaded = true;
        },
        error: error => this.uiContext.handleError(error),
      });
  }

  private loadHeaderActions() {
    this.headerActions = [
      {
        title: this.i18n.t('retire'),
        outline: true,
        icon: 'far fa-archive',
        handler: () => this.retireAsset(),
        hidden: () => this.asset.state === Assets.AssetState.Retired,
      },
      {
        title: this.i18n.t('transfer'),
        color: 'primary',
        handler: () => this.transferAsset(),
        hidden: () => true, // No functionailty in the PR
      },
      {
        title: this.i18n.t('refresh'),
        color: 'default',
        iconOnly: true,
        outline: true,
        icon: 'far fa-sync-alt',
        handler: () => this.loadAsset(),
      },
    ];
  }

  get title() {
    return [this.asset.brand, this.asset.type].join(' ');
  }

  tabSelected(selectedTabId: TabIdentifier, event?: any) {
    if (!(event instanceof TabDirective)) {
      return '';
    }

    this.selectedTabId = selectedTabId;
    if (this.selectedTabId === TabIdentifier.OVERVIEW) {
      this.loadAsset();
    }
  }

  private loadTimelineEntries() {
    this.timelineEntries = [];

    if (this.asset.log) {
      this.timelineEntries.push(...this.asset.log.map(entry => LogEntry.deserialize(entry)));
    }

    if (!_.isEmpty(this.asset.notes)) {
      this.timelineEntries.push(...this.asset.notes.map((entry, index) => Note.deserialize({ ...entry, index })));
    }

    this.timelineEntries.sort(Dated.sortBy);
  }

  updateAsset(event) {
    const updateRequest = event;
    updateRequest._id = this.assetId;
    this.assetManagementService.updateAsset(updateRequest).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.uiContext.showSuccessToast(this.i18n.t('success'), this.i18n.t('save_successful'));
        this.loadAsset();
      },
      error: error => {
        this.uiContext.showErrorToast(error);
      },
    });
  }

  private retireAsset() {
    this.updateAsset({ state: Assets.AssetState.Retired });
    this.loadAsset();
  }

  private transferAsset() {
    // Todo: Transfer
  }
```

here is the unit test:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockAssetManagementService = {
      getAssetById: jasmine.createSpy('getAssetById').and.returnValue(
        of({
          notes: [
            {
              _id: '1',
              userId: '1',
              lastUpdatedDate: new Date(),
              note: 'Test',
              notifyUsersByEmail: false,
              usersMentioned: [],
            } as Note,
          ],
          log: [
            {
              date: new Date(),
              event: LogEntryEvent.ASSET_CREATED,
              userId: '1',
              data: {},
              getDate: () => new Date(),
            } as LogEntry,
          ],
        }),
      ),
    };
    mockUIContext = createSpyFromClass(UIContext);
    mockI18n = createSpyFromClass(I18NextService);

    
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppTestingModule, CommonModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: AssetManagementService, useValue: mockAssetManagementService },
        { provide: I18NextService, useValue: mockI18n },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { params: of({ workflowId: 'testAssetId' }) } },
        { provide: UIContext, useValue: mockUIContext },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    const assetManagementService = TestBed.get(AssetManagementService);
    const i18n = TestBed.get(I18NextService);
    const activatedRoute = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
    const uiContext = TestBed.get(UIContext);
    
    comp = new AssetViewComponent(assetManagementService, i18n, activatedRoute, uiContext);
  });
  
  it('should create the component', async(() => {
    expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should call ngOnInit', async(() => {
    comp.ngOnInit();
  }));

  it('should not call loadAsset', () => {
    comp.tabSelected(TabIdentifier.OVERVIEW);
    expect(mockAssetManagementService.getAssetById).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should call loadAsset', () => {
    comp.tabSelected(TabIdentifier.CHARGEBACKS);
    comp.tabSelected(TabIdentifier.OVERVIEW);
    expect(mockAssetManagementService.getAssetById).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```